# Probability of a random chair being empty and having a seat to the right which is not empty is $\frac{m(n-m)}{n(n-1)}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let there be a round table with $n$ chairs. $m$ people choose their chair (max 1 person per chair) and let $m < n$.

I am pretty sure that the probability of a random chair being empty and having a seat to the right which is not empty is $\frac{m(n-m)}{n(n-1)}$

How can I show that this is indeed the right formula for calculating the probability of the described event?

I have tried for several hours but I can't  figure it out, maybe  someone of you finds an easy solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is correct. The probability that the chair is empty is $\frac{n-m}{n}$.  **Given** that it is empty, the probability the chair to the right of it  is occupied is $\frac{m}{n-1}$. Multiply.

Comment: There are $n$ chairs, of which $n-m$ will be empty. Since we choose a chair at random, with all chairs equally likely, the probability we choose an empty chair is $\frac{n-m}{n}$. It is the same idea as we have $n$ balls, of which $m$ are red and the rest blue. If we pick a ball at random, with all balls equally likely, then then probability of picking a blue ball is $\frac{n-m}{n}$, because there are $n-m$ blue balls.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Jake: Nice question, which is different enough to be worth asking separately.

Comment: Or maybe not different enough. The problem can be solved quickly by defining random variables $X_1$ to $X_n$ by $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th chair is empty but the one to the right is not. Then the number of groups is $X_1+\cdots+X_n$, so by the linearilty of expectation and the answer above we have $E(X)=\frac{m(n-m)}{n-1}$